# only one section header

Tags: ios, tableview

I'd like to have the section header (for an UITableView) for the uppermost cell  only , a sort of header for the table that sticks to the top, showing some additional information about the uppermost cell.

is it somehow possible? if not (as I suppose since I've carefully read all the documentation) do you have any idea how to replicate this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own view to use as the header.  It will be simplest to make your custom header view be a sibling of the table view, and position it so that it's above the table view on the screen.

Since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, your table view's delegate is also a scroll view delegate and receives the `UIScrollViewDelegate` messages.  You want to implement this method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Each time your delegate receives that message, you want it to look at which table view row is at the top of the table view (using `[tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tableView.contentOffset]`) and update the contents of your custom header view accordingly.

Comment: indexPathForRowAtPoint:tableView.contentOffset I was missing this API. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the Apple documentation for UITableView.  The property you're looking for is tableHeaderView.

Comment: which doesn't stick on the top and isn't any how linked to the uppermost cell

Answer (score 0):

This is hard (not impossible) with `UITableViewController` because it forces the tableView to be the root view.

If you implement your own controller, inherit from `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`.

You must adopt the data source and delegate protocols, and implement the methods appropriately, but then you have a normal view as your root view.  You can then add a `UITableView` in any location and size you want, with anything you want around it.

The only real restriction is static table views you build in IB.  However, in that case, you can implement view controller containment, and just parent your table view controller into another controller, and give it a specific view to take over.

The first option is dead simple, but the second is an advanced technique, and you need to understand view controller containment to do it right.